# Why two instances of AssetFileDescriptor not equals if refering to the same file?

Tags: java, android

I am building instances of AssetFileDescriptor using AssetManager's openFd() method as follows:

```
String path = "myDir/myfile.wav";

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(path);

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor2 = getAssets().openFd(path);

boolean areEquals = descriptor.equals(descriptor2);
```

In this case, areEquals is false, because the AssetFileDescriptor class doesn't override the equals() method.

This is causing problems when using AssetFileDescriptor instances as keys in a HashMap.

Shouldn't two instances of AssetFileDescriptor be equals when refering to the same asset file ?

Comment: why should they be the same ?

Comment: `AssetFileDescriptor` is definitely not meant to be used that way.

Comment: @Blackbelt they describe the same file, so I think they should be equals

Comment: *This is causing problems when using AssetFileDescriptor instances as keys in a HashMap.* ... then use paths ... *they describe the same file, so I think they should be equals* ... no, as they may point to different offsets ...

Comment: @Matdev you're in confution between the technical equality and the functional equality.

Comment: I am not confusing them; I think they are some cases where the equals method should reflect the functional equality, and I think that's the case here. But I take @Selvin point, even though the equals method could also compare offsets and length

Comment: @matdev [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.java) does not lie. It does not work like that. So your only hope here is to inerith that class and implement equals yourself or wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, because `AssetFileDescriptor` doesn't override `equals()` you have to assume that the `equals()`you used is comming from `Object`, so the mehode you had run is :

```
    public boolean equals(Object paramObject) {
        return (this == paramObject);
    }
```

Is it corresponding to the equality you wanna test ? 
If not you have to override `AssetFileDescriptor.equals()`

Comment: I checked the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.java) it really does not reimplement equals.

Comment: So he can write static `boolean AssetFileDescriptorUtils.equals(AssetFileDescriptor fd1, AssetFileDescriptor fd2){...}` OR write `class MyAssetFileDescriptor extend AssetFileDescriptor`. The second solution is the worste one.